# Not able to see the results by using Dbms_Output.Put_Line

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am not able to see the results by using Dbms_Output.Put_Line in sql developer. The result is shown only once. When I execute it again, it is not shown. 
I checked a lot of workarounds described in google, but those haven't worked for me.

I am executing following:

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN

 Dbms_Output.Put_Line('hello1');

END;
```

It should print 'hello1', everytime it executes, but instead, it does so only during first run. I have also tried the only resolution available on google: 
Opening the 'view' menu and clicking on 'dbms output'. I got a dbms output window at the bottom of the worksheet. I then added the connection by clicking on plus sign appearing in window. But even that did not work for me.
Please can anyone help me here?

Comment: Works for me.anonymous block completed
hello1

anonymous block completed
hello1

anonymous block completed
hello1

anonymous block completed
hello1

anonymous block completed
hello1

anonymous block completed
hello1

Comment: What version of SQLDeveloper?

Comment: The version info is : Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @getshere - that's the database version; what is the SQL Developer *client* version? You can get that from Help->About. (Also, are you sure you aren't seeing new output, but the previous output is just scrolling out of view in the Script Output/Dbms Output windows? What happens if you change the string?)

Comment: This is what I got :    Java(TM) Platform 1.6.0_20
Oracle IDE 3.0.02.83
Versioning Support 3.0.02.83

Comment: 3.0.02 is pretty old; I don't have a version older than 3.0.04 lying around to verify this on, and that's [from 2011](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev30downloads-1525485.html). Are you able to upgrade to [a newer version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)? Current version is 4.1.0, and that certainly doesn't show this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version is being used at my workplace and is remotely hosted, so there is a remote possibility that they will upgrade by acting on my advice.

For now I am able to generate output by this simple workaround:
To generate the output I have to select and run all the statements(including `'set serveroutput on;'`) as a whole, every time I need to generate output. Note that executing `'set serveroutput on;'` and

```
BEGIN

 Dbms_Output.Put_Line('hello1');

END;
```

separately is not working. I need to select the statements at once and run together in one Go. That's the way it is working for me.

Comment: You mean selecting everything and clicking 'run statement'? Running as a script doesn't work without selecting it? Good luck getting the upgrade anyway though; make sure you mention you're on the early adopter release (3.0 EA2), not a production release *8-)

Answer (score 1):

The version your are using, 3.0.02.83, was an early-adopter (i.e. beta) release. There seems to have been at least [one known issue with `dbms_output` in that version](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2146294), and this looks like an extension of those problems. As noted in comments, the behaviour you are experiencing in that old version isn't reproducible now.

Unless you have a pressing need to be on an old unsupported beta version, you should upgrade to a later release. At the time of writing the current version is 4.1.0.19, and you can get that from [the SQL Developer downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).